# I did a Push on Git repository and everything is gone. How do I revert that using GIT GUI tool?

Tags: git, github

I did a push to github repository and everything in the main branch is gone.

How do I revert that?

I used Git GUI Tool

Answer (score 1):

You need to push the commit that you want to the remote repository.

On the command line, that would be

```
git push <remote-name> <source-commit>:<target-branch>
```

- `<remote-name>` is the name of the configured remote (typically `origin`).
- `<source-commit>` describes the commit (revision) that you want to push to the remote.  This can be the name of a local branch, or a commit hash, or other things.
- `<target-branch>` is that branch in the remote that you want to push to (usually `master`)

Comment: How do I do that using Git GUI tool?

Comment: @HemantVc: Remote, Push; it doesn't seem to have options for pushing other branches.